# Cannot find module greenlet

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

Trying to install https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO on Google App Engine, module is installed on lib/greenlet.so, but not loaded.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 239, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 298, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 84, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~adroit-nimbus-531/1.374699491503674061/main.py", line 23, in <module>
    from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit, join_room, leave_room
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~adroit-nimbus-531/1.374699491503674061/lib/flask/exthook.py", line 81, in load_module
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb.tb_next)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~adroit-nimbus-531/1.374699491503674061/lib/flask_socketio/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from gevent import monkey
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~adroit-nimbus-531/1.374699491503674061/lib/gevent/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from gevent.hub import get_hub, iwait, wait
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~adroit-nimbus-531/1.374699491503674061/lib/gevent/hub.py", line 8, in <module>
    import greenlet  # http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet/
ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (initgreenlet)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably won't work as it uses C extensions not available on GAE.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27

It's the sort of thing there are other tools for (task queues etc) on GAE anyway.